# swift UIImage blue square

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage

I have a project where any image I try to call using .setImage shows a blue square instead of the image.

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "o.png"), for: [])
print(sender.tag)
```

any help is greatly appreciated

Edit: I forgot to mention this is setting an image for a button inside of an IBAction

Comment: sender is class of UIButton, right ?

Comment: what's the `sender`?

Comment: I have 9 buttons each with a unique tag. Printing sender prints the tag name

Comment: That said, the button is the sender

Comment: ugh sleep deprivation lol - printing sender.tag prints the button's tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A couple things.  I've never seen `setImage` used with an empty array of states.  Even though the docs say "if the state isn't specified, Normal will be used", try explicitly stating the states where you want your image to be applied:

Try doing this:

```
// let's make sure sender is really a button
if let aButton = sender as? UIButton
{
    if let nonBlueImage = UIImage(named: "o.png")
    {
        aButton.setImage(nonBlueImage, for: [.normal, .selected, .highlighted])
    } else {
        print("couldn't find o.png")
    }
} else {
    print("suprise, sender wasn't really a button")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, explicitly stating is best practice. It still works if you set it with [] instead of using a UI State, but an image needs to be initialized on the button first in the storyboard.

Answer (score 1):

**Basic :** `UIButton` can not be set directly like as we do for `UIImageView`. You have to define at which state of `UIButton` you'r setting the image. Even if you wanted to set title for `UIButton` you have to define the button state like below

```
sender.setImage(<your_image>, for: .normal)
```

so replace you'r code with below lines and try

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "o.png"), for: .normal)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Before I tried this, I assigned one of the buttons with an image instead of leaving it blank before trying to set the image in ViewController.swift. I was then able to remove the image and can now set an image in code... so I guess it needs to be initialized with an image before (your_image for []) will work, but it does work as well

Answer (score 0):

This occurs when the image you are trying to access is not in `.png` format.
Or else the image does not exist in the bundle at all.

Comment: This is one time it occurs, but in this case, the image was in the bundle and in .png format

Comment: Okay @froggomad Share right answer if you get . Thanks in advance :).

Comment: the best answer feature did that for us ;)

Answer (score 0):

Use `setBackgroundImage` property instead of `setImage` property. It will work:

```
sender.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "o.png"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

After clicking the sender state changed as selected.

So kindly clear the tint color of sender

otherwise

```
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "o.png"), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set UIControlState instead of [].

So for example, if you want to change the image for normal state of UIButton,

then should use .normal instead of [].

ex: sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "o.png"), for: .normal)

You can just use .selected, .highlighted, something like that.

Just refer to this url please.
https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicontrolstate

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will work

```
let image = UIImage(named:"o")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
sender.setImage(UIImage(named: image), for: .normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not direct answer to this question but I was also getting a blue circle while setting image in extensions of `UIImageView` and `UIButton`.
For me rendering the image with `alwaysOriginal` did the trick.

```
let image = UIImage(named:"placeholder")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
```